# Directly draw a rectangle on IMFMediaBuffer using C++ code

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, ms-media-foundation

Currently, I try to modify sample from [Media Foundation Transform](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Media-Capture-Sample-adf87622). I tend to achieve the following

- Perform face detection in C++ code.
- Pass back the face detected coordinate to C# code.
- Let C# draw detected face rectangle on the screen.

I completed step 1. However, I am being sucked on step 2. I am facing similar problem as this : [How to get feedback from MediaCapture API in Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12907538/how-to-get-feedback-from-mediacapture-api-in-windows-8). I cannot find a way, to make my C++ MFT code, talk with C# code.

I was thinking another workaround. **Directly draw a rectangle on `IMFMediaBuffer` using C++ code.**

However, I do not see Microsoft provides such APIs to do so. If not, what is the correct way I can use?

Comment: Can you set pixel colors in that buffer?

Comment: Ya. I can set the pixel value in the buffer. But, it will be tedious to draw shape (rectangle, circle, ...), by filling in pixel 1 by 1.

Comment: Maybe not tedious, but requiring some thinking if you have never done this before.

Answer (score 0):

If you can set pixel colors it should be fairly simple to draw a rectangle with a loop.

```
for (int y = top; y <= bottom; y++)
    for (int x = left; x <= right; x++)
        pixels[y * width + x] = color; // pseudocode
```

Drawing just borders of a rectangle is just 4 separate loops.

Simplest way to draw a circle:

```
for (int y = -r; y <= r; y++)
    for (int x = -r; x <= r; x++)
        if (x * x + y * y < r * r)
            pixels[(center.y + y) * width + center.x + x] = color; // pseudocode
```